# Is it possible to detect when UIButton is touched?

Tags: swift, swift3, uibutton

I have multiple buttons in my `FirstViewController` each button when its clicked, will take me to the `SecondViewController`. inside `SecondViewController` there is a `textfield`, the `textfield.text` should be assigned the a specific value based on the button clicked.

Is it possible to detect which button pressed?

Comment: Have you solved it ? or still facing issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

The button passes itself as the `sender` argument of the action, if you declare your action like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonWasTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    // use button…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a segue, the button is the `sender` in [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare).  You can override this on the initiating view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
  // use button…
```

And the target view controller is [available as a property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboardsegue/1621916-destination) on the segue object.

Comment: I am using segue and my button is declared this way "func kholaHospital(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromKhola", sender: self)
    }" how can I add this function in prepare function to detect when it is touched?

Comment: You need to set a variable on your view controller to the value of the button.

   self.someVariable = button.text

Then you need to attach that value to your SecondViewController in prepareForSegue.